# Unable to get API call logs from specific application running on Android using Charles

Tags: charles-proxy

I am facing problem in getting API call's data using charles for one particular application. I have already done proxy settings on my android and iPhone. I am able to see logs from all other apps running on my mobile except a particular app.

Could there be any limitation imposed by Android app?

Answer (score 0):

This is not limitation caused by Android app, but more likely caused by Charles.

Charles is a proxy, but only proxy for HTTP(S). There are many app that communicate with server using non-HTTP protocol (raw socket for example). In such condition, Charles is not able to intercept the requests and responses.

Comment: thats not true in my case. All APIs are using HTTPs protocol